# Call a WCF Service using just manual code (no config or autogen code)

Tags: wcf, endpoint

I am loosely following the method in [WCF The Right Way ... The Manual Way](http://code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0809101&page=5) to setup my WCF Service.

I have a manually generated proxy class that looks like this:

```
// Setup a client so we can call our web services.
public class EmployeeClient :IEmployeeService
{
    private readonly IEmployeeService EmployeeChannel;

    public EmployeeClient(Binding binding, string address)
    {
        var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(address);

        EmployeeChannel = new ChannelFactory<IEmployeeService>
                                 (binding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel();
    }

    public EmployeeResponse SaveOrUpdateEmployee(EmployeeContract employee)
    {
        return EmployeeChannel.SaveOrUpdateEmployee(employee);
    }
}
```

I then want to call some of these services.  But I don't want to use any config files (I am setting up some integration tests and I don't want more dependencies than needed.)

I am currently trying to call them like this:

```
serviceHost = SelfServiceHost.StartupService();

employeeClient = new EmployeeClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), 
                                    SelfServiceHost.StartUpUrl);

EmployeeResponse employeeResponse = employeeClient.SaveOrUpdateEmployee(emp);
```

When I do that I am getting this exception:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: Content Type text/xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:8090/EmployeeService.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'..

What do I need to do to get a call to my service working with code only?

Comment: For future reference and as of this comment's posting, the tutorial link posted in the question no longer loads the tutorial. I've been unable to locate the tutorial elsewhere, but was able to find a quick reference to this tutorial with sample project code here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114139/WCF-The-Right-Way-A-Quick-Reference-Guide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what you dessribe the binding is not configured in a compatible way.

I suspect that the WCF host has `wsHttpBinding` and your client-side has `BasicHttpBinding` or similar...

see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f29cd9c8-3c89-43d2-92ae-d2a270ab86b9/